# laravel- Eloquent relationship between users, user infos, user addresss, and user contacts

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a bunch of models in my laravel project. There are four models, meaning four tables in my database. Namely the models are `User`, `UserInfo`,`UserAddress`,`UserContact`. The user table is the master table and the structure of the columns are as below:

```
users -> id , email, password,....other unimportant stuff.
user_info -> id, name, identity num, ......
user_address -> id, user_id, address1, address2,address3, shipping address,....
user_contact-> id, user_id, mobile_num,emergency_num,......
```

As you can see, the `id` column is the key identifier to know the entire information for any user. I am trying to define an eloquent relationship between them four and couldn't know if I am correct. This is what I have so far:

User Model:

```
 public function user_info(){



        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UserInfo');
    }


    public function user_address(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UserAddress');

    }



    public function user_contact(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UserContact');
    }
```

UserInfo Model:

```
    public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');

    }


    public function user_address(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserAddress');
    }


    public function user_contact(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserContact');
    }
```

UserAddress Model:

```
    public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }



    public function user_info(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\UserInfo');
    }



    public function user_contact(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserContact');
    }
```

UserContact Model:

```
    public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }


    public function user_info(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\UserInfo');
    }


    public function user_address(){


        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\UserAddress');

    }
```

So the question is that I am unsure for example, is user contact the child of user address or the other way round?

Is user contact the child of user info?

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Appreciate it.

Comment: don't you have `user_id` on `user_info` table?

Comment: You are providing too little details to be able to answer your question. E.g. your `User` model hasOne `UserAddress` and hasOne `UserContact` why would the `UserAddress` model then hasMany `UserContact`? And which key is your foreign key in the `user_address` table pointing to the `user_address` table? This was the first thing I saw, but there seem to be more inconsistencies and you need to provide a better explanation of the use-case for us to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I apologized as I mistyped some information in my code before it was changed. You can ignore those for now. Basically, the a user have one user info but can have more than 1 address and more than 1 contacts. This is how it goes. Is that enough information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi just keep all relations in User model and access them through it. In other Model just relation back to User Model. I am your structure modifying little bit, let user add multiple address check box for default shipping address, also multiple contacts if you want you can keep just one contact also.

```
users -> id , email, password,....other unimportant stuff.
user_info -> id,user_id ,name, identity num, ......
user_address -> id, user_id, address,shipping address,....
user_contact-> id, user_id, mobile_num,emergency_num,......
```

User Model

```
public function user_info(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UserInfo');
}


 public function user_address(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserAddress');
 }

  public function user_contact(){

      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserContact');
  }
```

in you all other user related models just add this

```
public function user(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

you can access relation through user model

```
$user_info = UserInfo::with('user')->first();
$user_info->user->user_contact();
```

if just user Model

```
$user = User::with(['user_info','user_contact','user_address'])->first();
echo $user->user_info->name;
```

**update**

user_id is the foreign key in each table other than user table, if you want to test the relations create User db seed and 4 factories (user, user_address, user_contact, user_info) to fill fake data, after creating models and data in database fetch first User and call its relations, do the same thing for other models fetch first record and call user relation from this model.

this is my UserTableSeeder class run method

```
public function run()
    {
        factory(App\User::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($user) {
            $user->user_address()->save(factory(App\Models\UserAddress::class)->make());
            $user->user_contact()->save(factory(App\Models\UserContact::class)->make());
            $user->user_info()->save(factory(App\Models\UserInfo::class)->make());
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do I need to specify foreign key/primary key?

Comment: Also, how do I test out the relationship of these after finishing the models?

Comment: Laravel has a registration auth done. Is it possible to split the register into three different users?  For example, I want to register but I can choose between register form of normal user, special user, or dealer. Is it possible? Each user register form are different than each other, maybe some have extra text to field,etc

Comment: Yes its possible use this package you can define roles, user, special user or dealer and give me them permission as per their roles https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Comment: is the set up a lot?